# Is befrest like oneSignal?

Tags: android, web

Does befrest work like oneSignal and give me a button for subscribe in web? How to every user can get uid and chid in web and andriod?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? https://bef.rest/documentation
And what do you mean by 'button', do you mean a HTML button or the 'poopup' the browser gives to enable/disable the notifications?

Comment: Yes. I checked documentation. Of course an html button  and popup for accept notification